# Phase transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, ferromagnetism

Can transition from ferromagnetism exist in 1D chain of spins?

I know that:
$$\Delta F = 2J - kT\ln(N)$$

in the spin $1/2$ Ising model, where $N$ is the number of ways in which we can create the domain wall. For large $N$ and $T\neq 0$, second term will dominate and $\Delta F$ will be negative resulting in no long range ordering of spins and hence $0$ magnetization. But for $T = 0$, first term dominates and we have all spins up or all down in the ground state resulting in non zero magnetization. That means we can have a phase transition from ferromag/antiferromag to paramagnetism only at $T =0$. Is this argument correct for non existence of Ferromagnetism in 1D?

Comment: Are you asking "Is there long range order at finite temperature in the 1D Ising model?" or "Is this a valid argument to show that there is no long range order in 1D?". If it is the first then long range order in 1D is prevented by the [Mermin-Wagner Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem). If it is the second then I would have to say, based solely on your argument, what prevents a phase transition at a small, but non-zero temperature?

Comment: At finite non zero T also, based on J, $\Delta F$ can be +ve and hence there can be phase transition. But I have never come across such an argument and have read that Ferromagnetism can't exist in 1D.

Comment: @BySymmetry : Mermin-Wagner theorem has nothing to do with the absence of discrete symmetry breaking in one-dimensional systems (it applies to systems with a _continuous_ symmetry). Nevertheless, there are very general theorems showing that one-dimensional systems (at least with bounded spins and interactions decaying not too slowly) cannot undergo a phase transition at positive temperature. See, for example, Section 6.5.5 in [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

[NB: The correct relation is $\Delta F = 2J - kT\ln(N-1)$]

> For large $N$ and $T\neq 0$, second term will dominate and $\Delta F$
>   will be negative resulting in no long range ordering of spins and
>   hence $0$ magnetization.

Yes. The first term ($2J$), which represents the energy penalty in creating a "domain wall" (i.e. in flipping all the spins on one side of a randomly chosen one), is completely negligible when $N$ is large. The second (entropic) term will result in a decrease in $F$, therefore favoring the creation of more and more domain walls and preventing long range order from being established.

> But for $T = 0$, first term dominates and we have all spins up or all
>   down in the ground state resulting in non zero magnetization.
>    That means we can have a phase transition from ferromag/antiferromag
>   to paramagnetism only at $T =0$. Is this argument correct for non
>   existence of Ferromagnetism in 1D?

Yes, this is correct. In the 1D Ising model (and actually in any 1D model), phase transitions can only occur at $T=0$.

For a discussion of this, see K. Huang, *Statistical Mechanics*, $14.3$.